.NET 8 Isolated Function triggered without running function code
I have recently created an Azure Function app (BlobTrigger) using .NET 6 and that worked perfectly. Then I decided to migrate to .NET 8 and started running into the issue below. I have tried various solution including creating a new .NET 8 function app from scratch to try and eliminate dependency issues without any luck. Basically trigger is logging that it has executed successfully without actually running:

I am out of options at this point and not sure on how to resolve this, the storage account is StorageV2 (general purpose v2) but I can't see that being a problem as the app was running fine with .NET 6?
Packages included are:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Data.AppConfiguration" Version="1.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets" Version="1.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs" Version="6.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration" Version="7.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I have been playing around with the startup but this is what I have currently got running:
using Azure.Data.AppConfiguration;
using Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace ViyaTransferService
{
    public record ConfidentialClientAppScopes(string[] Scopes);

    internal class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            var config = InitializeConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder());

            var host = ConfigureHostServices(config)
                .Build();

            Console.WriteLine($"running host");
            await host.RunAsync();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder ConfigureHostServices(IConfiguration config)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"loading services");
            return new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config => { config.AddUserSecrets<Program>(optional: true, reloadOnChange: false); })
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
                    services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
                    services.AddScoped(x => new ConfigurationClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppConfigConnectionString")));
                    services.AddScoped<IFileTransferService, FileTransferService>();

                    services.AddSingleton(x => ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder...
                        .Build()
                    );

                    services.AddSingleton(x => new ConfidentialClientAppScopes(...) + "/.default" }));

                    services.AddAzureClients(clientBuilder =>
                    {
                        clientBuilder.AddBlobServiceClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ViyaStorageConnectionString"));
                    });

                    services.AddLogging();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    ...
                });
        }

        static IConfiguration InitializeConfiguration(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            string? startupenv = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT");
            Console.WriteLine($"startupenv: {startupenv}");

            string cs = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppConfigConnectionString");
            builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(cs);

            if (startupenv != "Development" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultUrl) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientId))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"loading keyvault");
                builder.AddAzureKeyVault(...);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"loaded config");
            return builder.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true).AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
        }
    }
}

As mentioned I have tried creating a new app in .NET, I've also tried changing from a custom connection string to the default AzureWebJobsStorage, Ive added tried adding AddBlobServiceClient as an AzureClient in the startup, I've tried to look into the logging to confirm that the trigger is executing, I've tried overwriting the file and adding multiple files thinking that maybe it was a file issue (previously used a file with spaces in the name) and a few other things such as changing out packages etc.

can you share your function code(blob trigger)?

I had a similar issue with my function when running locally as well. In the end I had to deploy to QA every single time and use logging for testing.

When your actions inside triggers does not work properly and It executes triggers successfully. May be processfile function is not working properly.
Make sure to check any exceptions, I would suggest to use Try and Catch method.
This is my code  for a simple File transfer
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.IO;

namespace FunctionApp4
{
    public class Function
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function> _logger;
        private readonly IFileTransferService _fileTransferService;

        public Function(ILogger<Function> logger, IFileTransferService fileTransferService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _fileTransferService = fileTransferService;
        }

        [Function("Function")]
        public void Run([BlobTrigger("test/{name}",Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Stream blobstream, string name)
        {
            using var blobStreamReader = new StreamReader(blobstream);
            var content = blobStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name} \n Data: {content}");

            var sourcePath = "C:\\Users\\Vivek\\Documents\\upload.txt";
            var destinationPath = ".\\upload.txt";

            var transferResult = _fileTransferService.TransferFileAsync(sourcePath, destinationPath);

            _logger.LogInformation("Trigger executed successfully");
           

        }
    }

    public interface IFileTransferService
    {
        Task<bool> TransferFileAsync(string sourcePath, string destinationPath);
    }

    public class FileTransferService : IFileTransferService
    {
        public async Task<bool> TransferFileAsync(string sourcePath, string destinationPath)
        {
            
            try
            {
                File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath, true);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error transferring file: {ex.Message}");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

}

using FunctionApp4;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.AddSingleton<IFileTransferService, FileTransferService>();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();


OUTPUT:

My upload.txt file was copied from source to my FunctionApp4\bin\Debug\net8.0 folder.

